# I'm trying to get information from a beatmap from Osu (the game), but I keep getting the same error

Tags: python

```
import ossapi

api_key = "My api key"
headers = {"User-Agent": "MyAwesomeApp/1.0"}
api = ossapi.Ossapi(api_key, headers=headers)
beatmap_id = "1514385"
beatmap = api.get_beatmaps(beatmap_id=beatmap_id)[0]

filename = f"{beatmap_id}.txt"  
with open(filename, "w") as f:

    # Write the beatmap information to the file
    f.write(f"Title: {beatmap.title}\n")
    f.write(f"Artist: {beatmap.artist}\n")
    f.write(f"Creator: {beatmap.creator}\n")
    f.write(f"Difficulty name: {beatmap.version}\n")
    f.write(f"Stars: {beatmap.difficulty_rating}\n")
    f.write(f"Circle size: {beatmap.circle_size}\n")
    f.write(f"Overall difficulty: {beatmap.overall_difficulty}\n")
    f.write(f"Approach rate: {beatmap.approach_rate}\n")
    f.write(f"HP drain: {beatmap.hp_drain}\n")
    f.write(f"Max combo: {beatmap.max_combo}\n")
    f.write(f"Length (in seconds): {beatmap.total_length}\n")
    f.write(f"BPM: {beatmap.bpm}\n")
    f.write(f"Source: {beatmap.source}\n")
    f.write(f"Tags: {beatmap.tags}\n")
    f.write(f"Download link: {beatmap.download_link}\n")

print(f"Beatmap information written to {filename}")
```

"This is the error:

> TypeError: Ossapi.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers'

What am I doing wrong? What I should change in the code to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Ossapi uses a `header` argument. The main arguments it uses are one for a client ID and another one for a client secret. So I believe it should be like this:

```
import ossapi


client_id = "client Id here"
client_secret = "client secret here"
api = ossapi.Ossapi(client_id, client_secret)
beatmap_id = "1514385"
beatmap = api.get_beatmaps(beatmap_id=beatmap_id)[0]

filename = f"{beatmap_id}.txt"  
with open(filename, "w") as f:

    # Write the beatmap information to the file
    f.write(f"Title: {beatmap.title}\n")
    f.write(f"Artist: {beatmap.artist}\n")
    f.write(f"Creator: {beatmap.creator}\n")
    f.write(f"Difficulty name: {beatmap.version}\n")
    f.write(f"Stars: {beatmap.difficulty_rating}\n")
    f.write(f"Circle size: {beatmap.circle_size}\n")
    f.write(f"Overall difficulty: {beatmap.overall_difficulty}\n")
    f.write(f"Approach rate: {beatmap.approach_rate}\n")
    f.write(f"HP drain: {beatmap.hp_drain}\n")
    f.write(f"Max combo: {beatmap.max_combo}\n")
    f.write(f"Length (in seconds): {beatmap.total_length}\n")
    f.write(f"BPM: {beatmap.bpm}\n")
    f.write(f"Source: {beatmap.source}\n")
    f.write(f"Tags: {beatmap.tags}\n")
    f.write(f"Download link: {beatmap.download_link}\n")

print(f"Beatmap information written to {filename}")
```

In order to get a `client_id` and `client_secret`, you need an Osu account.

If you have one, go to the user settings page and add a new OAuth application. The site will generate them for you.